# Accessing camera height of Qt QML Map

Tags: qt, 3d, qml, location

I want to create a line between two points in a QML Map, like the MapPolyLine, but it has to be in 3d. Right now, even if I add altitude to MapPolyLine, the line sticks to the surface of the map.

I tried searching, but everyone seems to say that we need to implement custom solutions. So I overlaid a scene3d on top of the map. I'm trying to align the camera of the scene3d with the camera of the Map.

I'm having difficulties with the zoomLevel property.
The zoomLevel property maps from 1(whole world is seen) to 19(closest). I want to be able to transform that to the 3d location of the camera such that they align perfectly. Is there some way I could do that?

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.12

import Qt3D.Core 2.12
import Qt3D.Extras 2.12

import QtLocation 5.12
import QtPositioning 5.12

import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Item {
    width: 200
    height: 200

    Button {
        id: viewAllButton
        text: "View All"
        onClicked: {
            camera.viewAll()
        }
        anchors.top: parent.top
        x: parent.width/2
    }

    Rectangle {
            id: sceneRect
            anchors.top: viewAllButton.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

            color: "Red"
           Map {
               anchors.fill: parent
                id: testMap
                plugin: Plugin {
                    id: esriPlugin
                    name: "esri"
                }
                zoomLevel: 20

                property real oldTilt : tilt
                property real curTilt: tilt

                property real oldBearing : bearing
                property real curBearing : bearing

                property var oldCenter

                property real oldZoom: zoomLevel
                property real newZoom: zoomLevel

                onTiltChanged: {
                    curTilt = testMap.tilt
                    camera.tiltAboutViewCenter(oldTilt-curTilt)
                }
                onBearingChanged: {
                    curBearing = testMap.bearing
                    camera.rotateAboutViewCenter(  camera.rotation(oldBearing - curBearing, Qt.vector3d(   0.0, 1.0, 0.0) ) )
                }
                onCenterChanged: {
                    var curCenter = QtPositioning.coordToMercator(testMap.center);
                    if(!oldCenter)
                           oldCenter = QtPositioning.coordToMercator(QtPositioning.coordinate(0.0,0.0));
                    else{
                        if(oldCenter !== curCenter)
                        {
                            var incrementX = 1000 * (curCenter.x - oldCenter.x)
                            var incrementY = 1000 * (curCenter.y - oldCenter.y)
                            camera.translateWorld(Qt.vector3d(-incrementX,0.0,-incrementY), Camera.TranslateViewCenter)
                            oldCenter = QtPositioning.coordToMercator(testMap.center);
                        }
                    }
                }
                onZoomLevelChanged:
                {
                    newZoom = (testMap.zoomLevel)
                    var increment = newZoom - oldZoom
                    camera.translate( Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 57 * increment),  Camera.DontTranslateViewCenter)
                }
            }
            Scene3D {
                id: scene3d
                focus: true
                aspects: ["input", "logic"]
                anchors.fill: parent
                cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio
                enabled: false

                Entity {
                    id: sceneRoot

                    Camera {
                        id: camera
                        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
                        fieldOfView: 45
                        nearPlane : 0.1
                        farPlane : 1000.0
                        position: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 40.0, 0.0 )
                        upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 )
                        viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
                    }
                    components: [
                        RenderSettings {
                            id: renderSettings
                            activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
                                camera: camera
                                clearColor: "transparent"
                            }
                        }

                    ]
                    PhongMaterial {
                        id: material
                    }
                    Transform {
                        id: transform
                        rotationX: 90
                    }

                    CylinderMesh {
                        id: cylinderMesh
                        radius: 0.2
                        length: 10.0
                    }
                    Entity {
                        id: cylinderEntity1
                        components: [transform, cylinderMesh, material ]
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    {
        // Set OpenGL requirements
        QSurfaceFormat format = QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat();
#if !QT_CONFIG(opengles2)
        format.setVersion(4, 1);
        format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
        format.setSamples(4);
#else
        format.setVersion(3, 0);
        format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile);
        format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLES);
#endif
        QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
    }
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Force OpenGL backend
    QQuickView view;

    view.resize(1024, 768);
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.setPersistentSceneGraph(true);
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: can you share your implementation?